# vcpkg: ignore internals version of package (qt5-base) and use external one?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, qt5, vcpkg

So far I have linked to a custom installation of Qt5 and used vcpkg for any other dependencies:

```
list(PREPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/qt/5.15.2/gcc_64")
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
```

But this fails if vcpkg has Qt5 (qt5-base) installed a package itself, as cmake will always prefer the vcpkg-internal package rather than my own qt5 installation.

How can I force vcpkg/cmake to ignore the internal qt5 package and use my external one instead? I am on a Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Comment: Maybe, do the `find_package()` first and evaluate the `QT5_FOUND` afterwards. If failed, set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and do the `find_package()` again. I must admit it's rather an idea/sketch to try out than a ready receipt. [CMake: find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html).

Comment: FYI: [SO: How to check if find_package found the package (boost)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10227005/7478597)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt work bc  I still need vcpkg for all the other dependencies and  also the prefix-path needs to be set even before the project() definition...

Comment: Found in an old `CMakeLists.txt`: `find_package(Qt5 5.9 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets CONFIG PATHS "${PLATFORM_DIR}/qt5")`. `PATHS` sounds like there can be multiple... (`PLATFORM_DIR` addressed a very specific directory which we introduced to ensure that every developer will use the exact same version to develop against. I also noticed that this interferes with `CMAKE_PREFIX_LIST`. So, this shouldn't be combined probably.)

Comment: Thanks once more, but sadly cmake  always prefers the  vcpkg-internal package over the  "config paths" provided one...